# Laravel File Exists function is not working when filename contains special characters

Tags: php, image, laravel-5, special-characters

I have a image with the name **The-seven-Churches-of-the-Revelation-&-Istanbul.jpg**

However, the filename is saved in the database in this format; **The-seven-Churches-of-the-Revelation-%26-Istanbul.jpg**

I am using the following code, and also ignoring **space**

```
$cover = str_replace('%20', ' ', $cover);

if (!\Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::exists(base_path($cover))) :
            echo "file not found";
endif;
```

Result is

> file not found

How can I deal with the special characters in the filenames?

Comment: remove `base_path`. that only gives you the file name and removes the file path. this will not work if the file is not in the same directory as public/index.php

Comment: i removed base_path but it's not working

Comment: sorry, I was thinking of basename(). carry on

Comment: according to https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-base-path it returns the installation directory of your laravel. So with your method above, it will actually look for the file relative to `/path/to/laravel/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may be having issues with the URL Encoded values, so `urldecode` may be your friend. [You can see the docs for this here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

```
$cover = urldecode($cover);

if (!\Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::exists(base_path($cover))) :
            echo "file not found";
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below any of 2
this is working fine. i have check this.

$file =  base_path().'/uploads/The-seven-Churches-of-the-Revelation-&-Istanbul.jpg';

```
        if(file_exists($file)){
            echo  "File Found";
        }else{
            echo "File Not Found";
        }
```

or

```
$file =  base_path().'/uploads/The-seven-Churches-of-the-Revelation-&-Istanbul.jpg';

        if(!File::exists($file)){
            echo "File Found";
        }else{
            echo "File Not Found";
         }
```